# Changing the date format in C

Tags: c, date, formatting

My structure variable `temp_var[0].trade_date` has the value of `20100614`. I need to format this date like `6/14/2010`. Could anybody please help me put the date in this format?

Comment: is it stored as string (char*) or int ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use sprintf, like this:

```
//date
int numeric_date = 20110430;

//convert integer to string
char numeric_date_string[9];
sprintf(numeric_date_string,"%d",numeric_date);

//format the string
char date[11];
sprintf(date,"%.4s/%.2s/%.2s",&numeric_date_string[0], &numeric_date_string[4], &numeric_date_string[6]);
```